# how to simplify array enumerations in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, enumeration, simplify

so I have an array and I want to add 1 to all the items.

```
var arr = [2, 3, 6, 9]

for (index, x) in enumerate(arr) {

    arr[index] = arr[index] + 1

}
```

is there a simpler version of this? there's no reason to have 'x' in there. I know there's the alternate way of writing it this way:

```
arr[index] = x + 1
```

but that doesn't seem like enough reason to have 'x' there.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate `indices` of the array

```
var arr = [2, 3, 6, 9]

for index in indices(arr) {
    arr[index] += 1
}
```

Essentially, `indices(arr)` is the same as `arr.startIndex ..< arr.endIndex`, but it's simple :)

OR, in this specific case, you might want to:

```
arr = arr.map { $0 + 1 }
```

Comment: I've just started learning swift, but the .map function and how simple it is makes more sense to me. 
i'm not sure what indices is and what limitations it has over enumerate (or how it's better) but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: taking the `map` function a bit further I realized it's also possible to do these: `arr = arr.map { $0 * $0 + (2 * $0) }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a really good use case for the .map function.

```
var arr = [2, 3, 4]
arr = arr.map({$0 + 1})
// arr would now be [3, 4, 5]
```